# Depending child value to other child values in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to develop a parking mobile application using firebase as my database.

[image: Here is what my firebase database looks like, they are all member of the same parent node]

Here is a sample of my code,

```
 public long freeSlots;
 public String fp1status;

 //Firebase database connection declaration
fbase= new Firebase("https://justpark-acdb7.firebaseio.com/Firstfloor/");
final Firebase fbaseFreeSlots=fbase.child("freeSlots");
Firebase firebaseparking1=fbase.child("fparking1");


   //I get the freeSlots value everytime it changes and set my long freeSlots into it
    fbaseFreeSlots.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                freeSlots = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

   //everytime a parking slot gets freed or occupied, i set my freeSlots child, into either +1 or -1 depending on the action of the user.
    firebaseparking1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            fp1status = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if (fp1status.equals("Occupied")) {
                Fragment fp1;
                fp1 = new occupiedFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fparking1, fp1);
                ft.commit();
                if(freeSlots>0) {
                    freeSlots = freeSlots - 1;
                    fbaseFreeSlots.setValue(freeSlots);
                }

            } else if (fp1status.equals("Free")) {
                Fragment fp1;
                fp1 = new freeFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fparking1, fp1);
                ft.commit();
                if(freeSlots<28) {
                    freeSlots = freeSlots + 1;
                    fbaseFreeSlots.setValue(freeSlots);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

It is working but the values seems to messing up, i have firebaseparking(up to 28) and it all looks the same so i won't upload it to avoid the long code. is there any problem on my code? or is it possible to depend the data of a child(freeSlots) to other childs?(each parking slots) in firebase?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of automatically calculating values on the database side, thus you need to look for alternative solutions. Here's one idea that could also clean up all the repetitive code in your application:

- Instead of subscribing to every single `fparkingX` node in the database one-by-one with the same code (copy-pasted or not, still smells), subscribe to their parent directly.
  Value and child event listeners both work here, albeit need a little different thinking.
- Eliminate the `freeSlots` node from the database.
- Calculate the number of free slots in your client code.
  With a value listener, you get all the parking nodes in one snapshot, so iterating through the children and counting them is trivially simple. 
  With a child listener, you have to keep a local integer outside and increment/decrement as the child events arrive – again, pretty simple once you grasp the idea.

Comment: i have different fragments that depends on each fparkingX node in the database so i subscribed to them one by one. thanks for the replyy ! if you can, can you demonstrate the iteration through the children? would really appreciate it if you can give a sample. thanks again!

Comment: Personally, I think that Fragments are not the way to go here. A RecyclerView will give you much better performance and memory usage. `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` makes it very simple to set up. Anyway, I'll add an example later.